# How to insert admins and users into a login form in wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

[My Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9URPA.jpg)I want to create Library Management system in Wordpress. I have imported my login form which was in php. i wanna know how to add admin and other users to the db and how to redirect it to the next page.

Please Help Me . I am kinda new to the wordpress world

Answer (score 0):

May be I mistake.

That is you need

```
<?php wp_login_form( $args ); ?>
```

it generates complete finished LoginForm